# Открытие всех товаров из определенной категорий в меню с БД

Tags: php, mysql

Вывел название категорий из базы данных в меню, использовал след код

```
<?php 
$categories_q = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM 
`articles_categories` ");
$categories = array();
while( $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories_q) )
{
    $categories[] = $cat;
}
?>


<?php 
  foreach ( $categories as $cat )
{
?>
<li><a href="/articles.php?categorie=<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo 
$cat['title']; ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как осуществить чтобы из меню в категориях открывался весь товар по данной категории

При открытии идет ссылка 
http://app/articles.php?categorie=1
И номер категории в конце меняется в зависимости от категории

Прописывая номер id категории, но как сделать чтобы от туда открывались все товары этой категории, сейчас ссылка просто не найдена

Comment: как минимум описать обработчик get запроса на запрашиваемой странице.

Comment: обновил, добавил все что использую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри у тебя есть страница articles.php
добавь в нее такой код.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category_id =' . $_GET['categorie'];
$articles_from_cat = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
```

По идеи в $articles_form_cat придет массив со всеми статьями из категории которую ты передаешь после вопросика в урле.
В базе в таблице articles у тебя должно быть поле category_id, которое хранит id нужной категории.

P.S Учишься по хауди )) Он же там все объяснил. Слушай внимательней.

Comment: да по хауди учусь)) я вывел товар из определенной категории, все что он там показывалось у меня получилось, вот то что в конце не доделали, где вывод идет из меню, не получается

Comment: я могу конечно прилепить и создать для каждой категории отдельный файл и там прописать                    $articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = 2 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 99");
и выводить так категории

Comment: Если хочешь можешь добавить меня в вк, 
Я прошел все эти непонятные штуки, отвечу если что на вопрос быстро https://vk.com/ozopactus

Comment: но как сделать чтобы из меню прямо сразу выкидывало на товар нужной категории, не получается

Comment: Добавь в вк. Я расскажу тебе всю эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

на странице articles.php:

```
if ($_GET['categorie']) { // если запрос содержит переменную categorie (category/categories)
    $articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `category_id` = '" . (int)$_GET['categorie'] . "'"); // тащите посты с переданным id категории. 
}
```

[get/post howto](http://www.php.su/learnphp/vars/?external)